# How to sort contents of a file.txt in python numerically

Tags: python, sorting

So I'm currently working on sorting out the scores within a text file with their corresponding name. This code does sort out the code numerically but prints out \t and \n as well. I am a beginner, I could barely wrap my head around .strip and item.rsplit.

I did \t to make the space in the file and \n to append the new inputs on a new line. I wanted it to make it look like names and scores are separated in columns, is this correct? is there a much simpler way of separating the 2 and being able to sort the scores numerically?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
name= input('What is your name?: ')
score=input ('What is your score?: ')

a=(name)
b=(score)

file = open("newfile.txt", "a")
file.write (a + '\t' + b+'\n')
file.close()

sorting=('How would you like to sort the scores?: \n\
1. Ascending \n')

sortchoice = int(input(sorting))
if sortchoice ==1:
    with open("newfile.txt", 'r') as file:
        sorted_data=sorted(file.readlines(),
                           key=lambda item: int(item.rsplit("\t",1)[-1].strip()))
        print (sorted_data)
```

Comment: This looks okay. However, I'd point you to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of SO since your program works.

Comment: Oh woah I didn't know about this, this actually helps alot thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just `strip()` the new line `\n` and `split()` on the tab character `\t` after creating `sorted_data` and then, using `" ".join()` to join the split string back together, seperated by space characters. Then you can print it again:

```
with open("newfile.txt", "r") as f:
    sorted_data = sorted(f.readlines(), key=lambda item: int(item.strip().split("\t")[-1]))
    sort = [" ".join(line.strip().split("\t")) for line in sorted_data]
    print(sorted)
```

With some really random data, this prints:

```
['ki 332', 'kokp 2112', 'ko 2121']
```

---

Of course, this is just a result of `print()` printing your `list`, and not it's contents. As such it cannot format the printed text with it's `\t` and `\n`.

You can easily just print every line ***as it was entered*** with:

```
with open("newfile.txt", "r") as f:
    sorted_data = sorted(f.readlines(), key=lambda item: int(item.strip().split("\t")[-1]))

     # No need for extra splitting and stripping now.
     # sort = [" ".join(line.strip().split("\t")) for line in sorted_data]

    for line in sorted_data: 
        print(line)
```

Which now prints:

```
ki      332

kokp    2112

ko      2121
```

---

Additionally, the parenthesis here:

```
a=(name)
b=(score)
```

really have no practical meaning, you can do `a = name` and `b = score` with the same effect.

Comment: I'm sorry for being an inconvenience but can you explain how this works? so the lambda makes up a short function that splits the 2 things in the file into 2 lists. the -1 is binary and chooses the second list? How does this actually sort it? I'm sorry in advance, the code works perfectly though I'm just trying to figure out how to also add in how to reverse the order going from highest to lowest. Thank you.

Comment: The `lambda` function takes each line in your file, strips the `\n` and then splits it on `\t`. After splitting we get a `list` of two values `[name, score]`; using `[-1]` we index this `list` and get `score`. This score is used as a `key` by the `sorted` function which takes care of sorting (Using it's own sorting algortithm). If you want to reverse the sorting order, it's actually very easy, add a `reverse=True` argument when you call `sorted()` as so: `sorted(f.readlines(), key=lambda item: int(item.strip().split("\t")[-1]), reverse=True)`

Comment: thank you so much, this helped quite a lot. I actually understand it now, I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
name = input('What is your name?: ')
score = input ('What is your score?: ')

with open("newfile.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write (name+'\t'+score+'\n')


sorting = ('How would you like to sort the scores?: \n\
1. Ascending \n')    
sortchoice = int(input(sorting))

if sortchoice ==1:
    with open("newfile.txt", 'r') as f:
        data = [i.strip() for i in f if i.strip() != '']
        sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x.split('\t')[1]))
        for i in sorted_data:
            print(i)
```

First,

```
data = [i.strip() for i in f if i.strip() != '']
```

returns something like

```
['Foo\t23', 'Bar\t33', 'Baz\t10', 'foo\t222', 'bar\t11111', 'qwe\t0001']
```

As you can see, these are the file contents, split by `\t`. So we're using:

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x.split('\t')[1]))
```

`x.split('\t')` gives something like `['Foo', '23']`, and then we use slice `[1]` to get `'23'`.

Finally, use `int('23')` as the sorted key.